# add another column header on top to C# datagridview winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a bounded datagridview with a lot of columns (around 40) and I'm wondering if I can add another column header on top of the default headers made with the SQL query. So it would look like a multi-row column header with some spanned columns.

I've seen some solutions by painting custom column headers but they involve creating all the columns. What if I leave the default headers made with the SQL query and just add a spanned column on top of it, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridView` has no support for spanned columns.  You will need to either look at third party, custom rendering, or a second control parked just above your grid.

Comment: Do you have links for doing custom renders?